# F# tail call optimization with 2 recursive calls?

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

As I was writing this function I knew that I wouldn't get tail call optimization. I still haven't come up with a good way of handling this and was hoping someone else might offer suggestions.

I've got a tree:

```
type Heap<'a> =
| E
| T of int * 'a * Heap<'a> * Heap<'a>
```

And I want to count how many nodes are in it:

```
let count h =
    let rec count' h acc =
        match h with 
        | E -> 0 + acc
        | T(_, value, leftChild, rightChild) ->
            let acc = 1 + acc
            (count' leftChild acc) + (count' rightChild acc)

    count' h 0
```

This isn't isn't optimized because of the addition of the counts for the child nodes. Any idea of how to make something like this work if the tree has 1 million nodes?

Thanks, Derek

---

Here is the implementation of count using CPS. It still blew the stack though.

```
let count h =
    let rec count' h acc cont =
        match h with
        | E -> cont (1 + acc)
        | T(_,_,left,right) ->
            let f = (fun lc -> count' right lc cont)
            count' left acc f

    count' h 0 (fun (x: int) -> x)
```

Maybe I can come up with some way to partition the tree into enough pieces that I can count without blowing the stack?

Someone asked about the code which generates the tree. It is below.

```
member this.ParallelHeaps threads =
    let rand = new Random()
    let maxVal = 1000000

    let rec heaper i h =
        if i < 1 then
            h
        else
            let heap = LeftistHeap.insert (rand.Next(100,2 * maxVal)) h
            heaper (i - 1) heap

    let heaps = Array.create threads E
    printfn "Creating heap of %d elements, with %d threads" maxVal threads
    let startTime = DateTime.Now
    seq { for i in 0 .. (threads - 1) ->
          async { Array.set heaps i (heaper (maxVal / threads) E) }}
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously 
    |> ignore

    printfn "Creating %d sub-heaps took %f milliseconds" threads (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds
    let startTime = DateTime.Now

    Array.length heaps |> should_ equal threads <| "The size of the heaps array should match the number of threads to process the heaps"

    let rec reMerge i h =
        match i with 
        | -1 -> h
        | _  -> 
            printfn "heap[%d].count = %d" i (LeftistHeap.count heaps.[i])
            LeftistHeap.merge heaps.[i] (reMerge (i-1) h)

    let heap = reMerge (threads-1) E
    printfn "Merging %d heaps took %f milliseconds" threads (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds
    printfn "heap min: %d" (LeftistHeap.findMin heap)

    LeftistHeap.count heap |> should_ equal maxVal <| "The count of the reMerged heap should equal maxVal"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use continuation-passing style (CPS) to solve that problem. See [Recursing on Recursion - Continuation Passing](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/08/13/recursing-on-recursion-continuation-passing.aspx) by Matthew Podwysocki.

```
let tree_size_cont tree = 
  let rec size_acc tree acc cont = 
    match tree with 
    | Leaf _ -> cont (1 + acc) 
    | Node(_, left, right) -> 
         size_acc left acc (fun left_size -> 
         size_acc right left_size cont) 

  size_acc tree 0 (fun x -> x)
```

Note also that in Debug builds, tail call optimization is disabled. If you don't want to run in Release mode, you can enable the optimization in the project's properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: Won't the continuation function grow until the memory will eventually run out?

Comment: Genereally, yes, but that is considered OK. The stack, however, has a static size (set at load or compile time) for most languages, including F# as far as I know, so it would create a stack overflow far sooner than an out of memory situation could be created with CPS. In general, many computational problems need unbounded datastructures for arbitrary inputs, and whether you do this via an explicit datastructure or an "implicit" one like the ever-growing continuation is arbitrary: The data needs to go somewhere.

Comment: I had thought of trying to do that before, but talked myself out of it because I thought It would still blow the stack. After Joh suggested it I gave it a try hoping that I was wrong. But no, the count function still blows the stack. Here is my implementation... crud I can't do that here, lemme try with another answer. How do you post code into a reply?

Comment: `    let count h =
        let rec count' h acc cont =
            match h with
            | E -> cont (1 + acc)
            | T(_,_,left,right) ->
                let f = (fun lc -> count' right lc cont)
                count' left acc f

        count' h 0 (fun (x: int) -> x)`

Comment: Someone pointed out that tailcall optimization is disabled if the code was built in debug mode. Once I rebuilt in Release mode I was able to count a tree with 1 million nodes, sweet! Thanks for pointing that out @kvb.

Comment: Cool :) ... good to know this important point about "tail call disabled in debug mode".. as tail call is important for our "recusrive" neurons

Answer (score 5):

CPS is a good general solution but you might also like to consider explicit use of a stack because it will be faster and is arguably simpler:

```
let count heap =
  let stack = System.Collections.Generic.Stack[heap]
  let mutable n = 0
  while stack.Count > 0 do
    match stack.Pop() with
    | E -> ()
    | T(_, _, heap1, heap2) ->
        n <- n + 1
        stack.Push heap1
        stack.Push heap2
  n
```

Comment: What does `Stack[heap]` mean?

Comment: Construct a `Stack` collection from the given sequence, a list containing a single element (the value `heap`).